# Shopify GraphQL partial matching on query filter

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-app

I'm just getting started with the new Shopify GraphQL **Admin API**. I'm trying to retreive all products, where the `title` field contains a certain word.

Currently I can successfully retrieve a product by including the full product title (exact match):

```
{
  shop {
    id
    name
  }
  products(first: 10, query:"title:'RAVEN DUSTY OLIVE/SILVER MESH'") {
    edges {
      node {
        productType
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I want to partially match the title to display all products with the word "Raven" anywhere in the title, but the following returns no results:

```
{
  shop {
    id
    name
  }
  products(first: 10, query:"title:'RAVEN'") {
    edges {
      node {
        productType
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the partial matching working?

Comment: Have you tried asking the Shopify Tech team if they secretly slipped in some kind of operator support for a LIKE type operator? GraphQL is not SQL and there is no such thing as partial matching unless the underlying implementation has provided one. If Shopify has not published such a thing, you're out of luck there. Back to the basics of getting all products yourself, and then filtering in your own code. I imagine if enough people asked for partial matching, they would provide a function  operator for it, with a higher cost than just plain jane matching.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLazar, worked out after posting the question.. that indeed Shopify would have to have a resolver for this to work :( Back to the good old REST API for now, it at least supports some filtering on the title attribute out of the box. Will ping the Shopify team on it, so hopefully in the future we can maybe get it on the GraphQL API too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bjorn! This should work:

```
{
  shop {
    id
    name
  }
  products(first: 10, query:"title:RAVEN*") {
    edges {
      node {
        productType
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Check out the docs: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/search-syntax

Comment: Any tips on why "title:RAVEN*" sync would not be working for me? I have tried all the obvious things. Testing collections edge instead of products.

Comment: That [prefix query](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/search-syntax#prefix-query) works in this case. Unfortunately there is no suffix query. It will find a term that starts with raven, but a term like "craven" will not return.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try with

`query: "title:*${searchText}*"`

you can see two * at the initial and the end

Comment: This does not work. The search syntax only provides a prefix query – not a suffix query.